# Test scenarios steps dependencies management

Tags: test-management, test-design

I have many test scenarios with their steps written as Cucumber features. Each time I start developing new scenario, I have to read through different feature files and try to find whether I have the step I need already implemented by me in another scenario or will I have to create it from scratch. Moreover, as each step obviously depends on one more other steps (*e.g. you can't perform any operations before you log in*), this process sometimes become very tedious and prone to errors.

So I thought that if there was some tool that I could input my steps with their respective dependencies into and it could give the dependencies tree as an output, that would've been very helpful.

However I am sure that something like that already exists and possibly has a name. Does that sounds familiar to anyone? Any ideas what tools are there that can help me with test steps management?

Comment: TFS has shared test steps

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is just using rspec and NOT using Cucumber.

This is obviously a fairly drastic step so let me give more detail and how to address your specific issues, as just "don't use it" isn't a very helpful or practical answer.

Some organizations use rspec, some use cucumber and some use both.  I have observed several organization adopt Cucumber, only to abandon it within a year and just use rspec.
I have seen this happen for two principles reasons:

1) Cucumber takes maintenance.  Just as with all software and testing.  I have seen companies struggle to maintain their testing suites when they include cucumber.  As the tests grow the amount of maintenance overhead also grows and becomes increasingly burdensome and slows down development.

2) Cucumber takes discipline.  The idea is to involve business analysts (or at least *business analysis*) in describing the companies procedures.  The problem here is that this still needs to be done using a disciplined programmatic approach that may not be clear to a non-programmer or someone not used to organizing the definition of functionality is this manner.  When you need to start explaining concepts like DRY to them this shows the problem.  Yes DRY isn't that hard - but it's part of the programming world.  Next you'll be talking about dependency inversion - how it's simple, just parameters, and so it goes on.

#### My approach is to try and use the best of both.

I tend to use rspec and not use cucumber, however I use the following approach which lends itself heavily to Cucumber:

- Feature are written with Given, When, Then in mind, not the actual words but the meaning
- The above Given, When, Then sections[*1] are separated by a blank line
- One assertion per test[*2]
- Use rspecs `before :each` and nested levels of tests to run shared setup for multiple tests

[*1] This is the Gherkin syntax.
[*2] This rule is intentionally broken for feature specs due to the slowness of using real browsers.  Chrome headless (version 59) may change this.

Example for the login you mentioned:

```
describe "a set of tests" do
  before :each do
    login
  end
  it "test1" do
    stuff
  end
  it test2" do
    other stuff
  end
end
```

One final note: Even without this, I assume that you have created methods such as '`login_to_app`' that at least DRYs up the login part so that you just call `login_to_app` in all tests that require it, rather than duplicating the actual login steps themselves in each test.

My final comment is that in terms of being able to figure out which tests need which setup steps, there is no easy solution or tools to help with this currently.  I feel this is mostly because this requires human knowledge and expertise to determine what tests need what setup and how best to organize tests, nested tests, shared setup, etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this, I will take a look at rspec to see what it's about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about steps dependency management tool, but we can check if step def exits for scenario in a feature file.
One way is to check is by having a dry run.

```
@Cucumber.Options (dryRun = true)
```

Dry run will ensures that you have step definition for your scenarios without actually running it. This approach may not work always, depending on how you structure your scenario, but its still worth a try nonetheless. Let me know, if it works for you or not?